# session key between client and TGS in kerberos

Tags: java, kerberos

I'm trying to develop a kerberos application in java. Could some one tell how AS generate the session key between client and TGS.

Comment: are you asking for the code or the concept?

Comment: i need the concept and like to know is there a way it could be implemented in java

Comment: http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.de/2008/05/how-to-decrypt-kerberos-gss-ap-req.html

Comment: Thanks for that .. i went through that but i have to built my kerberos without using any kerberos libraries provided by java. This is an academic project . so do u know of any cryptographic libraries that will generate a session key

Comment: you would probably have to hack into sun jdks krb5 classes to figure out what you want to accomplish. Since you plan on reimplementing krb5 it makes sense